# SQLite FTS4 search with special characters

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, special-characters, fts4

I have an Android app which searches for data in an SQLite database with FTS4 virtual tables. It works fine, but when the data inside the tables contain special characters (like 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú' or 'ñ') the SQLite MATCH function gives no results. I'm lost at this point. Thanks.

Comment: What [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) are you using?

Comment: Well, I am not using any tokenizer, and I don't know how that works. My search is as follows: 

SELECT * FROM table1_fts4 WHERE table1_fts4 MATCH 'query';

Answer (score 0):

Attention: default tokenizer is really poor.
To get good results you should implement a custom tokenizer.
The path isn't so simple:

- find the tokenizer (with stemmer?) that should fit your need, or
  develop it
- glue it with sqlite.c sources
- glue a JNI interface to wrap the native library so it will be
  accessible from the dalvik VM
- use NDK to compile sqlite.c from scratch and prepare a dynamic
  library for Android

Here in stackoverflow you should find some good posts to start learning how to do that.

Look at these projects to get some good starting point:

- sqlite4java
- sqlcipher